# Flutter: Text overflow for a Text inside a Column not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Text(showing.title, style: browseTitle, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
    Text(showing.dates, style: browseInfo),
    SizedBox(
      height: 20,
    ),
    Text('Posted by: ' + showing.email, style: browseInfo),
  ],
),
```

This code produces this:
[image]

But the problem is that the textoverflow I put inside the text doesn't seem to be applying and the text keeps overflowing. How do I solve this so that the text doesn't overflow and it turns into an ellipsis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CheckOut this work perfect

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Text(
              showing.title,
              style: browseTitle,
              maxLines: 1,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
          Text(showing.dates, style: browseInfo),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Text('Posted by: ' + showing.email, style: browseInfo),
        ],
      ),
```